# How to configure routes in Rails 3 for nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, installation

In my application, a User has many Posts, and a Post has many Comments.  How should I configure the routing?  I have configured it like this:

```
resources :users do 
  resources :post do 
    resources :comments 
  end 
end
```

Some articles say this isn't recommended because it will be confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, It is not recommened. But Allowed in rails

You should use something like this

```
resources :users do
  resources :posts
end

resources : posts do
  resources :comments
end
```

As Deep Nesting Will create problems like, long path names in rails, and long urls in urls.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this approach specified in the question. But It may fail in long run. And It will be difficult for you to remember the path names, Lets keep it simple. Ultimately they provide same. Lines increased but gives u the flexibility to avoid unexpected consequences